# How to create a copy of a class with javassist?

Tags: java, javassist

With Javassist, how can I create an absolutely the same class as the one I have, but with a different name. I want to preserve all runtime annotations as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass cc = pool.get("OriginalName");
cc.setName("NewName");
cc.writeFile();
```

Comment: This will rename the class, while I need to create a new class (not touching the existing one)

Comment: I don't think it will delete the old class, have you checked?

Comment: Yes sure, it renames the class.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'renames the class'. Surely you are not saying it unzips the JAR file, deletes the .class file and the zips it again.

Comment: What do you think `writeFile()` is doing? Class is not in JAR file any more when it's available for JVM - it's in a real file. But I think you're right, your snippet works, just checked it again.

Comment: BTW, `ClassPool#getAndRename()` is even better and more elegant approach (see my answer)

Answer (score 5):

Works fine for me like this:

```
javassist.ClassPool.getDefault()
  .getAndRename("com.example.Foo", "com.example.Bar")
  .toClass();
```