# Javassist - How to inject a method into a class in JAR

Tags: java, jar

I am reading a class from `JAR` file and injecting a function. How do I write this back to the JAR file?

```
     // Load the class representation

   ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
   pool.insertClassPath( "c:/Test.jar" );
   CtClass cc = pool.get("com.test.TestFunction"); 
   CtMethod m = CtNewMethod.make("public void test2() { System.out.println(\"test2\"); }", cc);
   cc.addMethod(m); 
   CtMethod cm = cc.getDeclaredMethod("test1", new CtClass[0]);
   cm.insertBefore("{ test2();}");
   cc.writeFile("c:/Test.jar");  // Fails here
```

Exception in thread "main" `java.io.FileNotFoundException`: c:\Test.jar\com\test\TestFunction.class (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Classes are usually deployed in JARs. So if I want to inject performance entry/exit code into the application at designated key points, this is how you would do it to deployed applications.

Comment: This is a very bad idea. You shouldn't change the thing you're testing, even for performance. What if, god forbid, there is an error in your perf-monitor extraction code, that has the impact of adversely affecting your performance? The correct way to do this is instrument the jvm, which has an api for this sort of thing. Take a look at jprofiler (http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler).

Comment: I agree, bad idea is doing something blinded.  But I will be doing more then just performance monitoring and more about 'out of the box' features. Some of these features will be done using the more intimate/direct approaches such as using agents. But there are cases this is not possible for environments I am dealing with. I am just in search of other approaches while in the discovery phase. Thanks for the suggestion..

Answer (score 10):

I guess there is no simple method in Javassist that would update a JAR and replace an updated class with a new class.  So I created a JarHandler class that simply receives the parameters.

This is main class that does the injection

```
  public static void main(String args[]){
  ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
  pool.insertClassPath( "c:/Test.jar" );
  CtClass cc = pool.get("com.test.TestFunction"); 
  CtMethod m = CtNewMethod.make("public void test2() { System.out.println(\"test2\"); }", cc);
 cc.addMethod(m); 
 CtMethod cm = cc.getDeclaredMethod("test1", new CtClass[0]);
 cm.insertBefore("{ test2();}");

 byte[] b = cc.toBytecode(); // convert the new class to bytecode.
 pool.removeClassPath(cp);   // need to remove the classpath to release connection to JAR file so we can update it.
 JarHandler jarHandler = new JarHandler();
 jarHandler.replaceJarFile("C:/Test.jar", b, "com/test/TestFunction.class");

 }
```

This is the JarHandler Class

```
 public class JarHandler{
   public void replaceJarFile(String jarPathAndName,byte[] fileByteCode,String fileName) throws IOException {
      File jarFile = new File(jarPathAndName);
      File tempJarFile = new File(jarPathAndName + ".tmp");
      JarFile jar = new JarFile(jarFile);
      boolean jarWasUpdated = false;

      try {
=
         JarOutputStream tempJar =
            new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempJarFile));

         // Allocate a buffer for reading entry data.

         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int bytesRead;

         try {
            // Open the given file.

            try {
               // Create a jar entry and add it to the temp jar.

               JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(fileName);
               tempJar.putNextEntry(entry);
               tempJar.write(fileByteCode);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                   System.out.println(ex);

                   // Add a stub entry here, so that the jar will close without an
                   // exception.

                   tempJar.putNextEntry(new JarEntry("stub"));
                }


            // Loop through the jar entries and add them to the temp jar,
            // skipping the entry that was added to the temp jar already.
            InputStream entryStream = null;
            for (Enumeration entries = jar.entries(); entries.hasMoreElements(); ) {
               // Get the next entry.

               JarEntry entry = (JarEntry) entries.nextElement();

               // If the entry has not been added already, so add it.

               if (! entry.getName().equals(fileName)) {
                  // Get an input stream for the entry.

                  entryStream = jar.getInputStream(entry);
                  tempJar.putNextEntry(entry);

                  while ((bytesRead = entryStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                     tempJar.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                  }
               }else
                   System.out.println("Does Equal");
            }
            if(entryStream!=null)
                entryStream.close();
            jarWasUpdated = true;
         }
         catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);

            // IMportant so the jar will close without an
            // exception.

            tempJar.putNextEntry(new JarEntry("stub"));
         }
         finally {
            tempJar.close();
         }
      }
      finally {

         jar.close();

         if (! jarWasUpdated) {
            tempJarFile.delete();
         }
      }


      if (jarWasUpdated) {            
         if(jarFile.delete()){
           tempJarFile.renameTo(jarFile);
           System.out.println(jarPathAndName + " updated.");
         }else
             System.out.println("Could Not Delete JAR File");
      }
   }
```

This function simply creates a temporary JAR by writing the new class bytecode to it.
Then is goes thru all entries of the current JAR and writes all its entries to the temporary
JAR file except for the entry that is being updated (the bytecode was already written to it above). Then it removes the current JAR and replaces it with the temporary JAR using the same JAR name.

Comment: Can you provide a compilable example ?

Answer (score 2):

I want to reference to the followin StackOverflow Q&A: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005805/how-to-create-a-copy-of-a-class-with-javassist)

When you read the comments you see that it is not possible to write back to a JAR. This is also indicated by the IOException (FNFE) that is thrown. Or a stupid wisenheimer answer: If we read the JavaDoc into that problem, we see that the method is expecting a *directoryName*. [JavaDoc](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/html/javassist/CtClass.html#debugWriteFile%28%29)

I suggest to unzip the JAR, make the manipulations and then re-build (zip) the JAR.

Keep me posted on your thoughts.

Comment: Yes, sort of was able to tell that writeFile() was expecting a directory name as a parameter. I just could not for the life of me understand why it was possible to retrieve the class from a JAR and manipulate it in few methods and there not be any simple methods to write it back to a JAR. I could not even find any examples of this being done at all. I would think many developers would be dealing with JARs more then just classPaths.

Comment: I agree with the usage. I think the author of the package closely followed the OO principle "Tight cohesion but loose coupling" (or was lazy): All the function of manipulation classes are available (tight) but the JAR manipulation (coupling) is missing. - Do you mind posting your solution in order to help others to progress faster?

Comment: Not so sure I agree about the Tight Cohesion/loose coupling comment. That has to do with interfaces between classes and how they interact. In this case, manipulating bytecode in my opinion has 3 main functional areas. 1.) Locating the bytecode to manipulate/look at 2.) Actual manipulation/peeking 3.) write the new bytecode.     The package fell short on the third function when it comes to writing out to JARs. The package did the writing of the classfile methods, I could have easily done that myself as well. But was nice that it had the methods.

Comment: Wonderful, we're at a point where programing/coding turns from a fact-based topic to a philosophy :)